# XML Formation using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I am trying to create an xml document using the snippet shown below.

My code is as shown below:

```
require 'nokogiri'

builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do
    {
        action "GetApplication"
        email "apiorder@rently.com"
        password "f1467868c64f818c7b9394d85cc46d98"
        request {
            response_format "detailed"
            application_id "15544"
            render_applicant_extended_fields {
                ari_criminal_info ""
                ari_evictions_info ""
                limelyte_employment ""
                limelyte_drivers_license""
            }
        }
    }
end

req_body = builder.to_xml
```

However when I try to convert it into XML, I run into this error

[image]

How can I overcome this limitation? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please post code. How are you using Nokogiri?

Comment: @KaomTe Have updated my question . Pls take a look

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do--you have both `do` and `{}`; pick one block notation and use it. Your next issue will be that you need a single root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
require 'nokogiri'

builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do
  root {
    action "GetApplication"
    email "apiorder@rently.com"
    password "f1467868c64f818c7b9394d85cc46d98"
    request {
      response_format "detailed"
      application_id "15544"
      render_applicant_extended_fields {
        ari_criminal_info ""
        ari_evictions_info ""
        limelyte_employment ""
        limelyte_drivers_license""
      }
    }
  }
end

req_body = builder.to_xml
```

Comment: I know this will work, Is there a way how we can convert to XML without the root node being necessary.

Comment: Since`'Nokogiri::XML::Builder` is returning the XML as a string object, I could actually use the string object and manipulate the same to get to my required format. This is more of a dirty hack than a formal solution but guess will work-around with it for time being.

Comment: "I know this will work, Is there a way how we can convert to XML without the root node being necessary" - That is not what you asked in your question. Please phrase your question appropriately next time to prevent people wasting effort to answer something you already know.